# How downgrade Ubuntu Samba implementation

Tags: samba

A week ago I got some updates related to Samba and now authentication is broken. Windows and Android machines can connect to a Samba server just right, however Ubuntu rejects login credentials. This regression is applied on all Linux flavors sharing Ubuntu repository like Mint or Elementary OS. I hope downgrade instructions can be applied for all Linux.

Comment: Rather than blindly downgrading, why don't you see what changed in the Samba upgrade and change your config accordingly?

Comment: Why do I ask here? If I had a required expertise level I wouldn't ever  bother. Purpose of the forum get an expert advise, not a suggestion like Google your friend.

Answer (score 4):

Debian and Ubuntu don't support downgrading, so you might encounter further problems by applying this piece of advice.

According to the [related question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get), you can:

- Find out what other versions of Samba are available:

  ```
  sudo apt-cache showpkg samba
  ```

  Pick one.
- Install that particular version (`1.2.3+dfsg-0ubuntu1` here):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install samba=1.2.3+dfsg-0ubuntu1
  ```
- Ask the OS not to upgrade the package automatically anymore:

  ```
  sudo apt-mark hold samba
  ```

Since `samba` won't be upgraded anymore, this might block other updates.

Also, you'll have to follow the updates (by regularly running `apt-cache showpkg samba`, for example) to see when a suitable update appears.

Comment: Had this same issue with nvidia drivers. Purge the package, find the old version deb file, install it via dpkg, and pin the version number in your apt preferences under /etc/apt

Comment: There are too many unfulfilled dependencies to do this